# no attribute to destroy

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I have two functions the `top_signup_click` and the `top_login_click`. The `top_signup_click` function is below the `top_login_click` function. The `top_login_click` function doesn't work because `the_top_signup_click` function is below it. To fix that issue I'll have to put the `top_signup_click` above the `top_login_click` function, which does solve the issue but it also creates another issue, now the `top_signup_click` function doesn't work. For both functions to work they both have to be below each other, but I don't think that's possible. If you know any other ways to do this please help. I tried using global functions to fix it but it didn't work.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font
import tkinter.messagebox 

signup_button = None
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('360x460')

#login stuff
def login_click():
    readfile = open("emails.txt", "r")
    lines = readfile.readlines()
    isIN = False
    for line in lines:
        
        if f'{entry.get()}, {entry1.get()}' in line:
            isIN = True
    if not isIN:
        tk.messagebox.showinfo(message ="You got your email/password wrong, are you sure you signed in?")
    else:
        tk.messagebox.showinfo(message ="You hacker, the email/password is correct") 

def signup_click():
    file = open("emails.txt","a")
    file.write (entry.get())
    file.write(f', {entry1.get()}\n')

def top_login_click():
    global signup_button
    signup_button.destroy()
    login_button = tk.Button(root, text="Login", bg='royalblue', fg='white', command = login_click, width = 15, height = 2)
    login_button['font'] = button_font
    login_button.place(x=88,y=330)
#when the top sign up button is pressed

def top_signup_click():
    global login_button
    login_button.destroy()
    signup_button = tk.Button(root, text="Sign-Up", bg='royalblue', fg='white', command = login_click, width = 15, height = 2)
    signup_button['font'] = button_font
    signup_button.place(x=88,y=330)



top_font = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=14, weight='bold')
label_font = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=20)
button_font = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=14, weight='bold')

top_login_button = tk.Button(root,text = 'Login',width = 15, height = 3, command = top_login_click)
top_login_button.place(x=0,y=0)
top_login_button['font'] = top_font


top_signup_button = tk.Button(root,text = 'Sign-Up',width = 15, height = 3, command = top_signup_click)
top_signup_button.place(x=180,y=0)
top_signup_button['font'] = top_font


username_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Username: ' )
username_label['font'] =label_font
username_label.place(x=120,y=120)

entry = tk.Entry(root, width = 40)
entry.place(x=65,y=170, height = 30)

password_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Password: ' )
password_label['font'] =label_font
password_label.place(x=120,y=230)

entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width = 40)
entry1.place(x=65,y=280, height = 30)

login_button = tk.Button(root, text="Login", bg='royalblue', fg='white', command = login_click, width = 15, height = 2)
login_button['font'] = button_font
login_button.place(x=88,y=330)



root.mainloop()
```

The `top_login_click` function is on line 29-34 and the `top_signup_click` function is on line 37-42. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you mixed the `global`. Inside of `top_signup_click()` try saying `global signup_button` and `top_login_click()` say `global login_button`, do let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to comment this but seems like I don't have enough reputation but here is what I think.

You have set the variable `signup_button = None` right below the import statements so `signup_button` is not really a `tk.Button` object, instead it's a `NoneType` variable.

So just remove that statement and create

```
signup_button = tk.Button(<args here>)
```

and You should be good.

and try using place_forget() instead of destroy() IFF destroy doesn't work for you.

**Edit:**
What I also think in your case that you may not really need to destroy the `signup_up` button because you haven't created one yet. Think about it this way (based on the GUI that comes up on running your code) - on the landing screen of your app (the first screen that comes up), you have a login form with two entry boxes for email & pword and a login button, along with two more buttons called `top_login_button` and `top_signup_button`. So You DO NOT have a `signup_button` as of now (and according to your code `signup_button = None` it's not a button). So if a user now clicks on the `top_login_button`, the statement `signup_button.destroy()` will look for widget with the name `signup_button` (which is set to `None` by you) so it raises the error.

You code will run fine in a case where user clicks on `top_signup_button` before clicking on `top_login_button` because in that case the `signup_button` will be actually set to be a `tk.Button` object.

Comment: Now you have enough reputation ;) though I don't think this might be the correct reason why

Comment: @CoolCloud hehe Thanks :)

If you look at the code after all the function definitions, there is no widget with the name 'signup_button' which is to be destroyed in the function call. 

The OP may not actually need a 'signup_button' (I am saying this based on the GUI which comes up on running his code). 

And I made it work at my end with the above changes.

Comment: @ChociiMilk

Simply place them again on the GUI. like signup_button.place(x=10, y=10).
place_forget() method just removes (or hides) the widget from the GUI. The widget is still in the program memory so you don't even need to create the widget again.
{remember to use a global version of signup_button to avoid unboundLocalError - like you did in your other functions for other widgets.}

Comment: @ChociiMilk Do mark this as the correct answer, if it helped, so as to close this Q